# Searching for textbooks that teach math differently from other textbooks about the same subject.

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation, big-list

Famous examples would be LADR (which to an extent eschews determinants) and Aluffi's Algebra (which involves some category theory). I would like more books in this vein, that either teach differently than other books written on the same subject, or books that present proofs, theorems, and methods which are also not commonly taught in other textbooks. Thank you!

Comment: "Visual Complex Analysis" by Needham is surely different than other texts.

Comment: ‘Complex Analysis’ by Alan Beardon takes a very distinctive approach to highlight the topological nature of some properties of analytic functions. It proves or explains many things using winding numbers, without using integration. It is also one of the very few textbooks that takes Weierstrass’ approach seriously.

Comment: “Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces” by Paul Halmos is unique in that, despite its title, many if not most exercises in the book do not assume finite-dimensionality. The readers who have previous exposure in linear algebra thus have to stop relying on some techniques (such as diagonalisation) that are only guaranteed to work in finite dimensions, and rethink about the essence of some concepts in linear algebra.

Comment: The treatment of dual spaces in Greub’s “Linear Algebra” via bilinear pairing is enlightening. E.g. to view a *sesquilinear* form (such as an inner product) on a complex vector space $V$ as a *bilinear* form between $V$ and its conjugate space really demystifies the former.